# Find centre point of a rotated rectangle

Tags: c#, math, rectangles, centroid

In my application user points two points `PointA` and `PointB` on the same row (could be at any angle). So I have the following information

1. PointA coordinates
2. pointB coordinates
3. Distance between PointA and Point B
4. An Across distance (taken from user as input to draw other points)
5. Angle (calculated from pointA and pointB).

Based on this information, another application draws four points (vertices of rectangle).

What I have to do is, I have to find the centre point of those four points (rectangle) to be able to properly draw the rectangle bounded between those 4 points.

Right now I am able to draw the rectangle taking the centre as the pointA which obviously is incorrect. What formula should I use to calculate the centre of Rectangle so that I can draw a bounded rectangle?

**Image 1:**

[image]

**Image 2:**

[image]

**Image 3:**

[image]

**Image 4:**

[image]

**Image 5:**

[image]

As seen in the attached images, in every case rectangle is getting drawn with pointA as centroid. While I want the centroid to the centre of the FOUR points.

P.S: All angles are measured 0 degrees North.

Comment: Why do you need a center of those four points in order to draw the rectangle, when you can use **the four points** to draw it?

Comment: I dont have the four points. Only information I have is point 1-5 mentioned above.

Comment: Which angle? A, B and ...? Three points for an angle! Probably adding a sketch is the best option for us and you to understand!

Comment: Do you have coordinates of point **4**?

Comment: No, I have coordinates of only P1 and P2 (both on same row). I do have the height though.

Comment: What is "An Across distance (taken from user as input to draw other points)"?

Comment: thats basically "height" of the proposed rect. I have the width and height (Across distance). I need to know the centroid to draw the rectangle

Comment: So, you have two points **p1, p2** and the segment **p1p2** will always be the rectangle's width? Since you have different "height" input?

Comment: Here you go. See below.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have two points **p1, p2** and you need to draw a rectange (get other 2 points **a1, a2**) from these:

```
a1.x = p1.x;
a1.y = p2.y;
a2.x = p2.x;
a2.y = p1.y;
```

There you go, four points **p1, a2, p2, a1** (clockwise order) describe your rectangle.

---

#### Update:

```
var width = p2.x - p1.x;
var height = p2.y - p1.y;
var angle = 0;
var center = new Point(p1.x + width / 2, p1.y + height / 2);
```

---

## Update:

```
var center = new Point();
var angle = //you have it. Radians.
var height = // you have this as well.
var halfSegment = new Point((p2.x - p1.x) / 2, (p2.y - p1.y) / 2);
center.x = halfSegment.x + Math.Cos(angle - Math.PI / 2) * height / 2;
center.y = halfSegment.y + Math.Sin(angle - Math.PI / 2) * height / 2;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this before, but I cant draw a rect based on points, I have to have the centre point. The method available to me takes in the width, height, angle and centroid of the rectangle.

Comment: for angle 0, you answer works perfectly fine, but for a non zero angle, how do I calculate?

Comment: @WQad for a non zero angle, how do you imagine that rectangle with your 2 points? Can you draw it?

Comment: @Sigismondo sorry for not posting the images earlier. Took a little longer to get the images. Sorry about that :) Hope the updated question makes it easier to understand ...

Comment: Yes, Segment P1P2 is the width of rectange

Comment: @WQad that explains a lot -_-

Comment: @WQad I also updated it with " + Math.PI / 2", look.

Comment: @WQad angle is in radians. If you and want to use degrees, you need to convert it.

Comment: still not working .. with your changes, the rectangle is no where near

Comment: @WQad try replacing "-" with "+", this should work, I've done this a lot.

Comment: @WQad 0 degrees North is ... well, try swapping Sin and Cos with each other, because they are oriented for 0 degrees East.

Answer (score 0):

I think:

Let P0 = {x0,y0} and P1 = {x1,y1}

Let the vector V01 = P1 - P0 == {V01x = P1x - P0x, V01y = P1y - P0y}

Let the vector V03 = {V01x  * Cos(PI/2) - V01y * Sin(PI/2) , V01x* Sin(PI/2) + V01y * Cos(PI/2)

Width = Sqrt(V03x * V03x + V03y * V03y)

VN = V03 / Width == {V03x / Width, V03y / Width}

P3 = P0 + VN * Height

P4 = P1 + VN * Height

PC = (P0 + P1 + P2 + P3) / 4